# How can I use Prophet for per-location forecasting given overall sales data

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-prophet

I am using Prophet for Sales forecasting, and I have a several CSVs. Most of the represent sales data by date for a specific location (e.g. "Location1.CSV has "Jan 1, 2010, X widgets sold", etc.)

There's a master CSV which aggregates sales across all locations. I have used Prophet to forecast Sales across all locations and that works well, but the per-location data is very variable.

I'm seeing much higher Mean Average Errors (MAE) for per-store forecasts while the overall model has much lower MAE.

Is there any way I can use the overall Sales model to try to predict per-location sales? Or any alternatives to forecasting per-location Sales besides just using the raw sales data for that location?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your overall sales model to help predict the per-location sales in Prophet using the [add_regressor method](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#additional-regressors).

Let's first create a sample df, where `y` is the variable we want to predict (per-location sales) and `overalls` are the overall sales:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start="2019-09-01", end="2019-09-30", freq='D', name='ds'))
df["y"] = range(1,31)
df["overalls"] = range(101,131)
df.head()
            ds  y   overalls
0   2019-09-01  1   101
1   2019-09-02  2   102
2   2019-09-03  3   103
3   2019-09-04  4   104
4   2019-09-05  5   105
```

and split train and test:

```
df_train = df.loc[df["ds"]<"2019-09-21"]
df_test  = df.loc[df["ds"]>="2019-09-21"]
```

Before training the forecaster, we can add regressors that use additional variables. Here the argument of `add_regressor` is the column name of the additional variable in the training df.

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
m = Prophet()
m.add_regressor('overalls')
m.fit(df_train)
```

The predict method will then use the additional variables to forecast:

```
forecast = m.predict(df_test.drop(columns="y"))
```

Note that **the additional variables should have values for your future (test) data**. As you initially don't have the future overall sales, you could start by predicting `overalls` with univariate timeseries, and then predict `y` with `add_regressor` and the predicted `overalls` as future values of the additional variable.

See also [this notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/nicolasfauchereau/Auckland_Cycling/blob/master/notebooks/Auckland_cycling_and_weather.ipynb), with an example of using weather factors as extra regressors in a forecast of bicycle usage.